# jquery mobile, combine jquery mobile "pages" and internal pages

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a `index.php` file for the jQuery Mobile version of my site. Inside are two pseudo-pages. One the content (dynamically generated); the other a sitemap. Using `#(hash)` links I can switch back and forth between the two.

But links inside the content area that go to other URLs on the same domain (not jQuery pseudo-pages within the same document) won't work, unless I turn off AJAX Navigation. But then my `#` links don't work.

How can I have my `#` links between "pages" that are in the same document work, while still allowing for links that don't use the hash, but stay on the same domain to work?

Comment: You will have to disable ajax in those _external_ links. use `rel="external"` or `data-ajax="false"` ind the `a` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can selectively disable AJAX linking for links using the methods described in this part of the jQuery Mobile Documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/pages/page-links.html

> Links that point to other domains or that have rel="external",
>   data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax.
>   Instead, these links and will cause a full page refresh with no
>   animated transition.